# Create private route and public route with 404 not found page

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I use react router v5 to make an app router. I want to make a 404 not found page when user goes to any link that not listed in the router whether they are logged in or not.

Here is my app router:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route exact path="/redirect" component={Pages.Redirect} />
    <Route exact path="/login" restricted component={Pages.Login} />
    <Route path="*" component={Pages.NotFound} />
    <Navigation>
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/dashboard" component={Pages.Dashboard} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/my-playlist" component={Pages.MyPlaylist} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/new-released" component={Pages.NewReleased} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/search" component={Pages.CreatePlaylist} />
      <PrivateRoute exact path="/profile" component={Pages.Profile} />
    </Navigation>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

The problem is, when I goes to dashboard, profile, search, etc. The page will render 404 not found page, not the correct one. And if I type any url, the page will render `<Navigation>` component instead of 404 not found page.

How to solve this?

Update:

Everything works fine now. I wrap my privaterouter with the `<Navigation>` component so every private route is render inside the `<Navigation>`.

Here is the privateRouter:

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }: any) => (
  <Navigation>
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        isLoggedIn() ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect to="/login" />
      }
    />
  </Navigation>
);
```

Comment: What is `PrivateRoute`? Is this a custom component? There is no such thing as `PrivateRoute` in `react-router` that I can find.

Comment: Yes it's a custom component, but the documentation of react router v5 has an example of it. Shortly, it just a logic to redirect to login or dashboard

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include it for future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

The `<Route path="*" component={Pages.NotFound} />` matches all routes and renders. Nothing in the `Switch` after it is reachable.

## Solution

- Move the `Navigation` into a route *outside* the `Switch` with an array of paths it should be rendered with.
- Order the routes in inverse order of path specificity.

Example:

```
<Router>
  <Route
    path={["/dashboard", "/my-playlist", "/new-released", "/search", "/profile"]}
    component={Navigation}
  />
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/redirect" component={Pages.Redirect} />
    <Route path="/login" component={Pages.Login} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Pages.Dashboard} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/my-playlist" component={Pages.MyPlaylist} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/new-released" component={Pages.NewReleased} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/search" component={Pages.CreatePlaylist} />
    <PrivateRoute path="/profile" component={Pages.Profile} />
    <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="*" component={Pages.NotFound} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: May I ask you, why you remove `exact` from all the route except home?

Comment: @HeraZeus Sure! When you order the routes correctly, in reverse order of path specificity, there's virtually no need for the `exact` prop. It's only used here so the path `"/"` (*which matches all paths*) can only match and render the home page and allow the `path="*"` route to match anything that wasn't matched prior/above.

Comment: The routes works fine now, thank you. But the `Navigation` component don't read the path component as a children. Do I need to fix the `Navigation` component or you have other solution?

Comment: @HeraZeus Can you clarify what "don't read the path component as a children" means?

Comment: Previously, I wrap the route inside the `Navigation` component so that the component will render inside `Navigation` as children. But I fixed the route with your solution, The component in `PrivateRoute` don't render inside `Navigation`. I'm sorry I'm bad at explaining, hope you understand

Comment: @HeraZeus Ah, I see what you mean. I assumed (*hopefully correctly*) that the `Navigation` component was rendering the `children` under its content, so moving it out to its own route and rendering the routes below it *should* be roughly equivalent. If this isn't the case can you add the `Navigation` component to your question, or create a codesandbox of your code we could look at?